# XML generation and parsing from Core data in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I'm creating a simple iOS application consisting of a few UITableViewControllers. The information displayed in the view controllers will come from a xml file (that I'll include in the project's Resources or direct from dropbox or iCloud). The xml file's contents will be based on user input .

A few notes:

The data is based on the user input means not static. Ideally the app will load the data into "Core Data" from xml file.
Each additional run of the app will just pull data from some Core Data source (that I'm not completely familiar w/ yet) instead of re-loading it from the textfile.

right now I am using XMLwriter to generate simple xml file

Please guide me
thank you

Comment: y do u need to generate xml locally, as u said u ll receive from server/cloud.. u need to to just parse the xml received & save it to db, and just query the db using coredata & display in tableview..

Comment: @vishy, because first I need to generate xml based on the user input programmatically ,and then I am going to send it to server

Comment: to generate xml for server request it will be easy, just use formatted `NSString` method as all the xml nodes are static..

Comment: @vishy No, I am generating xml locally from my application ,not from a  server,I am sending it on server after generating xml file locally from my application

Comment: even i said samething.. have u tried by using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]` to generate xml?

Comment: @vishy Right now Its works with XMLwriter class,with managedobject ,but How I can share it via iCloud and dropbox

Comment: best thing is just create a new sample project detail view based with coredata.. run & check it out, how it uses coredata to retrieve & save data..

Answer (score 2):

The best pattern here seems to be to use the XML file to "seed" your Core Data database. This only happens the first time. After that you will never again use your XML file but simply update and sync your core data store.

This is far better than generating XML. The problem with XML files (like property lists) is that you have to write the entire file for each little incremental change. If you sync to a store somewhere online, this can take much too much time to be practical.

Assuming you can get a foundation object from the XML file, simply iterate through the object and insert a Core Data one by one.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in xmlArray) {
   Entity *newObject = [NSEntityDescription 
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity"
                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 
   newObject.attribute1 = [dict objectForKey:@"attribute1"];
   newObject.attribute2 = [dict objectForKey:@"attribute2"];
   //  etc...
}
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: Would please elaborate your answer in detail?, because as I am beginner for core data its little bit complex for me

Comment: Do you know how to get objects out of an XML file?

Comment: Yes I know, and i tried with getting all object and make it in to string

Comment: See my edit on how to insert objects into core data. If anything is unclear, you should read up on Core Data using the standard documentation, as  this is really basic stuff. [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).